# Will jQuery run faster if the HTML element name is added with the ID?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

below is a snippet of code I use for added data to a table when a div is clicked on:

```
$(document).on("click", "div#pos_product_id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>", function() {
    $("table#pos_till_products_list").each(function() {
        searchRow = $(this).find("tr#product_id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>").html();
        if (searchRow == null) {
            $("#pos_till_products_list tbody:first").prepend("<?php echo $product_build; ?>");
        } else {
            var qty = $(this).find("tr#product_id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?> .qty").html();
            qty++;
            $("tr#product_id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?> .qty").html(qty);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm new to using JS/jQuery, but as you can see I've added the HTML element in front of the ID's. I would like to know if by adding the HTML element, would it make jQuery perform faster? I think it would, as adding the elements name stops jQuery from searching all other HTML element ID's on a page and only target the HTML element you asked it to select.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but I'm guessing you're asking 'is selecting by id' faster. If so, then yes, that is the fastest method to select an element. However, in real terms the difference is so miniscule when dealing with an average set of elements it makes no perceivable difference whatsoever

Comment: It seems clear, the OP gets that IDs are faster than classes -- it stops at the first instance of an id and that's that. But the question seems to be #id vs. div#id as the selector, and that's a slightly different case. I might suggest actually digging into the jquery.js code, in particular the init function -- it's remarkably well documented as to how it processes selectors.

Comment: Yes, your example of **#id vs. div#id** is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the way the different frameworks handle selectors does impact speeds, but the impact will usually be fairly minimal. Take a look at [SlickSpeed](http://selectors.turnwheel.com/slickspeed.php) to see a benchmark comparison of an exhausting array of selector tests, from $("body") to $("div:nth-child(n)") on a number of different frameworks. For the most part, the difference is a matter of a millisecond or two, but it's an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I felt it would be faster. But I did not know how much faster. Maybe if the page is running on slow hardware like a Intel Atom running a full Windows 8 it will make a tiny difference if only very very tiny. Thanks @Snowmonkey.

Comment: If you have tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of a given selector, it will take processing time, but the DOM native selectors are usually being time-optimized. Also, regardless of library, I do recommend taking a look at what it is doing. Pop the hood and check the code!